# Continuity at a point of characteristic function iff the point is not boundary point

Tags: general-topology

I have been stuck on this problem for a long time ...Since the definition of continuity at a *point * is given in terms of supersets ,I am at loss of how to proceed here...

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $\chi_A:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be the characteristic function for some subset $A$ of $X$.
>   Show that $\chi_A$ is continuous at $p\in X$, if and only if $p$ is not an element of the boundary of $A$.
>   (Recall $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$, and $\chi_A(x)=0$ if $x\in A^c$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $f:X\to Y$ is continuous at a point $x\in X$ if for every neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$.

Fix $p\not\in A$.
If $\chi_A$ is continuous at $p$, then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $\chi_A(U)\subseteq (-1/2,1/2)$. That is, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $U\subseteq A^c$. Hence $p$ is not in the boundary of $A$.

Conversely if $p$ is not in the boundary of $A$, then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $U\subseteq A^c$. Thus $\chi_A(U)=\{0\}$ is a subset of any neighborhood of $\chi_A(p)=0$. Hence $\chi_A$ is continuous at $p$.

The case $p\in A$ is similar.

Comment: :Thanks for your answer ....Just for clarification :Is the reason you chose the interval (-1/2 , 1/2) is because zero is in this interval , and hence in the case p is an element of A , should an interval containing 1 be chosen??

Comment: @herashefat We need a neighborhood of $0$, and in order to deduce $U\subseteq A^c$, we need it to not contain $1$. For the other case find a neighborhood of $1$ that doesn't contain $0$.

Comment: Again thanks for your response ..I am wondering if we can say :p an element of A complement , instead of p not an element of A (in the first case)??

Comment: @herashefat Of course, because $p\in A^c$ is equivalent to $p\not\in A$.